# Right side drawer in a web app

Tags: drawer

I am creating a design which have multiple products in the table format. I want to show the the detail of the product by clicking the specific product. Shall i use right side drawer widget?

[image]

By clicking any of the product this drawer will show the details of the particular product. The drawer has tabs and scroll also. is that a good idea?

[image]

Please suggest your ideas..

Comment: Images are too small so it's impossible to see what kind of information and labels you have. Technically, there's nothing wrong with this approach as long as discovery process is easy. But it will depend on the details we can't see

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I will try to upload a clear picture.

Comment: "Is that a good idea" questions are almost always entirely subjective and result in opinion-based answers. Can you tell us what is making you question your choice? What do you see as detractors for using the Right Drawer pattern in this instance? What do you think makes it a good choice? How would it stand up against other patterns?

Comment: Do you want your users to save links to particular products, or share them with friends? Side panels make it hard to do that.

Comment: @Izquierdo Regarding link sharing, links to product details can go to an independent product details page. Even the drawer ought to have an option to upgrade to an independent details page.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a standard for naming this pattern/component. As a container, the correct name is probably Side panel.
Semantics aside, It pretty common pattern around more complex application in which you want to offer users possibility to not just to preview details, but also to edit content (inline editing), add items (add subtask), collaborate with other users (commenting) - without losing context of your grid selection below, without heading to full detail page and having to get back to the list in order to continue browsing and working on other items in the list.
Scrolling, tabs and expanding to full detail or larger view add to complexity, but if your users require that level of complexity, this is the right way to offer it while still mitigating being complicated (most important overview info in the viewport, secondary content behind tabs, inline editing, revealing progressively additional information as user interacts with the UI).
There are few considerations to keep in mind:

- Good part of columns below are going to be hidden behind it
- Consider adding it next to the table (shrinking table) if your users are in large part on very large screens (offer possibility of overlay for those with smaller)
- Offer possibility to quickly pass to next/prev item (keyboard, buttons in the panel) - Maybe you can disable closing on click outside of the panel, so users can interact with the table behind it and open other items in the panel
- Highlight the item in the table underneath, so it's clear what is opened in the side panel
- Offer inline editing if your users usually edit just few things - avoid making them to open special editing view just to add or remove a tag
- Offer few insights into the content behind the tabs - If there are no Comments in the tab, you can name it `Comments (0)`, so user doesn't have to click the tab in order to discover that there is nothing there
- List preview of content behind the tabs in the first overview tab - Few subtasks from the `Subtasks (99)` tab with a link `view all`
- Give users possibility to share a link to this view if the URL is not updated with the detail view id (when users visits it from the link, you can still automatically open the Side panel)
- Offer resizing options - dragging the border to resize the panel, offer narrower preview mode (like Notion) for users who need the table and just quick small preview of what's inside the items (some data that cannot fit into the table row like images, comments, graphs)
- Check other apps that are extensively using this pattern (Asana for example, Height app, Workday, Notion) and take look into the guidelines of their Design systems, for best practices and options

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your table to be always visible, you can show extra rows.
A complete example can be seen on [this website (Shield UI Grid demo)](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-rows/detail-templates).

Comment: I think that's perfect for a limited number of record infos. But if _all_ of them should be displayed, including **Images & Videos**, much of the info will be outside the bottom of the viewport at first, especially if you select a row in the lower part of the table.